# querying same table twice

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.  One is stock_by_month which keeps records on bookId, stockvalue and reportId.  The second table is book; which keeps records on BookId,BookTitle and bookprice.
The reportId is unique for every different month, so for 2010 october is 1, 2010 november is 2 and 2010 december is 3

The Task is I want to generate a report which will include book details and also give the stock value of current month(reportid 3) and the previous month(reportId 2).

I am new to this sort of complexity.  I am not sure if that is possible. if it is, I will be very grateful for any help.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a [join](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-JOIN.asp). There are plenty of tutorials on SQL out there, so read up on joins and you should see how you can implement your report.

Answer (score 0):

You should join the two tables to get all the information, then group by the reportid.  Below is some SQL to get you started but definitely read up on joins as Cameron suggested, and also on 'group by'

```
SELECT      m.bookId, m.stockvalue, m.reportId, b.BookId, b.BookTitle, SUM(b.bookprice) AS total
FROM        stock_by_month m
JOIN        book b 
    ON  b.PRIMARY_KEY = m.FOREIGN_KEY
GROUP BY    m.reportId, m.bookId, m.stockvalue, b.BookId, b.BookTitle, b.bookprice
ORDER BY    m.reportId DESC
```

Comment: Thanks very much the code run at first trial but it is listing all the values per each reportId. I want the books to list once and stock values in separate table columns. I dont know if I sound clear enough.

Comment: at any report generation cycle I need values for the current month and the previous months stock value together with the other book details

Comment: That sounds more like a subselect to me, I do not know of a way to do it in SQL without using subselects.

Comment: can you combine to one please<p>1. select sum(sale) as csale, sum(gift) as cgift from sale,gift,book,comment where sale.bkid=book.bkid and gift.bkid=book.bkid and comment.bkid=book.bkId and year=2010 and month=11  group by book.bkid,sale.bkid,gift.bkid order by book.bkId

<p>2. select sum(sale) as lsale, sum(gift)as lgift from sale,gift,book where sale.bkid=book.bkid and gift.bkid=book.bkid and year=2010 and month=10 group by book.bkid,sale.bkid,gift.bkid order by book.bkId

<p>3.select bk_title,bk_lang,bk_price,bk_loc, stock_date, from stock,book where stock.bkId= book.bkId order by book.bkid

Comment: my problem is combining these 3 queries into one any help will be appreciated